# Pygame Scaling 28x28 Pixels to 420x420

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pixel

Hello I ran into a bit of a problem. I am trying to create a GUI for the Mnist dataset and I need a window with 28x28 pixels however that is roughly 420x420 in screenspace. Which means every pixel should appear 15 times it's original size. I also need to draw to the Screen. I haven't found anything so far that actually works.

Thanks in advance. (If you need clarification please just leave a comment)

Pygame version 1.9.6

Python version 3.6.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trivial answer to this is to simply scale the bitmap with `pygame.transform.smoothscale()`, then `blit()` that to the screen.  However this scaling is computationally expensive.

It's fairly easy to define a "pixel" sprite that scales and positions itself based on a sub-size of the screen.  When the pixel is set to an `(x,y)`, this is simply translated to the scaled position on the screen.

I parameterised the screen size and pixel-count to easily scale the pixels to whatever is needed.

The code uses a list of co-ordinates to draw a bunch of pixel-sprites to the screen.

```
import pygame
import sys

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH  = 420
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 420
FPS           = 60
PIXELS_WIDTH  = 28  # How many big-pixels vertically
PIXELS_HEIGHT = 28  # How many big-pixels horizontally
# background & colours
INKY_BLACK    = ( 28,  28,  58)
EGG_YELLOW    = (255, 233, 132)

class PixelSprite( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    def __init__( self, x, y, width=WINDOW_WIDTH//PIXELS_WIDTH, height=WINDOW_HEIGHT//PIXELS_HEIGHT ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
        self.image  = pygame.Surface( ( width, height ), pygame.SRCALPHA )
        self.rect   = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x * WINDOW_WIDTH  // PIXELS_WIDTH
        self.rect.y = y * WINDOW_HEIGHT // PIXELS_HEIGHT
        self.fill( INKY_BLACK )  # off

    def update( self ):
        pass

    def fill( self, colour ):
        self.image.fill( colour )



### MAIN
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
SURFACE = pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE
WINDOW  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), SURFACE )
pygame.display.set_caption("Big-Pixel Sprite Test")


pixels = pygame.sprite.Group() 
for coords in [ ( 8,10 ), ( 18, 10 ), (6,15), (7,16), (8,17), (9,17), (10,17), (11,18), (12,18), (13,18), (14,18), (15,18), (16,17), (17,17), (18,17), (19,16), (20,15) ] :
    x,y = coords
    pixel = PixelSprite( x, y )
    pixel.fill( EGG_YELLOW )
    pixels.add( pixel )

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done  = False
while not done:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN ):
            if ( event.unicode == 'q' or event.scancode == pygame.K_q ):
                done = True

    # Repaint the screen
    pixels.update()
    WINDOW.fill( INKY_BLACK )
    pixels.draw( WINDOW )

    pygame.display.flip()
    # Update the window, but not more than 60fps
    clock.tick_busy_loop( FPS )

pygame.quit()
```

[image: pixel-sprite-output.png]

Comment: Thank you very much great approach. Works nicely!